# Why is the word for origin and destination off-topic?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question: [Word for an Origin and Destination without regard for route [closed]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125178) was closed as off-topic. I can't figure out why.

I know an (unfortunate) edit to the question indicated naming of programming terms (known off-topic) but the question has a real answer without neologism or variable naming.

I realize the question is a year old, but I want to vote to reopen, removing the irrelevant part about naming programming (wasn't part of the ORIGINAL unedited question.)

As an aside, I'm struggling with the difference between programming naming and the general gist of Single Word Requests or phrasing that would be otherwise acceptable, even if oh, by the way, this is being used for programming.

Comment: The reason given: [This question appears to be off-topic because it is about naming (including programming)](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125178/word-for-an-origin-and-destination-without-regard-for-route#comment258123_125178).

Comment: I've voted to reopen. Unless I've completely misunderstood the question, ***terminus*** doesn't suit because it implies an ***end*** point (and it's feasible in OP's contexts some locations might in fact be be "departure only"). And ***leg*** doesn't work because that describes *a **[sub-] journey** passing between two points* (not at all the same thing as the collective term for all such points). I think the ban on asking for program variable names applies if that's the *only* reason, so if that aspect can (even just "in principle", not "actually") be removed, it doesn't justify a CV.

Comment: But *endpoint* or *waypoint* is a valid answer to the question and *IMO* is a good question for this site.

Comment: @SrJoven: I've no idea what if any English term could be a hypernym of both journey **start** and **end** points. For many years I produced applications for public transport providers, in which context people use ***reference points*** and ***timing points*** (and sometimes ***way-points***, but they're more AmE to me). But whereas any such "point" could be the start or end point for any individual *passenger's* travel, most of them wouldn't be the start or end of the "containing" journey from the viewpoint of the driver (or more precisely, *vehicle*, since *driver* might change "mid-trip").

Comment: @FumbleFingers an end is an end, in geometry, especially. There is no start unless it's a vector. Point A or Point B, they're at opposite ends of the journey.

Comment: @SrJoven: Well, let's not get bogged down in comments about possible *answers* to the question. The ***point*** (sorry! :) of this *Meta* question is whether that question on the *main* site should be/remain closed - and if so, on what grounds.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I see you didn’t read the *Foundation* trilogy.